# how to create event in google calendar using php (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-calendar-api

I have try to create event in google calender using php (Codeigniter) but not working please check my below php (Codeigniter) code

```
require_once APPPATH.'third_party/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once APPPATH.'third_party/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

$event = new Google_Event();
$service = new Google_CalendarService($event);
$event->setSummary('Appointment');
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2017-09-03T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2017-09-03T10:25:00.000-07:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
$attendee1 = new Google_EventAttendee();


$createdEvent = $service->events->insert('My calendar Email', $event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [PHP Quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php) for Calendar API as a reference since Codeigniter also uses PHP. However, this demo only shows how to get the list of events. To create events, use the PHP implementation in [Create Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events):

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
    array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```

Comment: i have use this code but not working and please give me class library link(Google_Service_Calendar_Event) and with full example

Comment: require_once APPPATH.'third_party/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/vendor/autoload.php';    this link call in codeigniter and setup your code with change $calendarId but generate error like Message: Undefined variable: service and Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object